# KnockoutJS visible binding not working

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I'm stuck at a simple code which is to make the `type` that is `a` visible only if it of type `a`. I' have used `KnockoutJS` for the same. I have tried a lot but I'm not able to find out the mistake.

HTML:

```
 <a href="#" data-bind="click: changeType('b')">change the type</a>
 <span data-bind="visible: isType('a')">a</span>
```

JS :

```
function viewModel = {
    var self = this;
    self.type = ko.observable();
    self.isType = function(type) {
    return type == self.type();   
};
self.changeType = function(para){
    return function(){
    self.type(para);
  }
};
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/npbb333e/) for above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/npbb333e/4/

```
var viewModel = function(){
  var self = this;  
  self.type = ko.observable();

  self.isType = function(type) {  
    return type === self.type();
  };

  self.changeType = function(para) {   
      self.type(para);    
  };
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```